# HTML linking html pages

Tags: html

I have configured 4 virtual hosts on a debian box.
The Document root for the first virtual host is /var/www/first/. Inside this directory I have the index.html. The other virtual hosts have different document roots like /var/www/second/ etc. I have second.html and soon for these virtual hosts. The index.html provides links to the second.html. I am able to load the index.html, but when I click on the link, it never goes to the link. In the error log I can see that that it is trying to access the second.html from /var/www/first/second. This is how I have tried to create a link.

```
 <a href = "../second/second.html">Click here to go second</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

`./` and `../` make the link relative to the current directory (`first`, in your case). Because of this, what your computer thinks you want is "the thing called `second.html` in the directory `second` in the current directory". You would have to use `<a href="/var/www/second/second.html">Click here to go second</a>` to get the desired results.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. But the document root of the hostname gets appended to the href, thus resulting in 404 error